# Logical Directory For Games & Icons

Tags: icons, directory

To my knowledge the /opt/ directory is a good directory to store your appimages and tarball applications. What would be a logical place to store games like emulator ROMs and ISOs?

Also what would be a good location for icons?

I want this directory to be accessible by all users on the machine, so I don't want to have them in my /home/me/...... directory.

Comment: Icons generally stored on `/usr/share/icons` subdir or `~/.local/share/icons`, if you want the icons to be used by all user—you place them to `/usr/share/icons`. Assuming that what you want.

Comment: @Jim Would it be accepting and logical to have a /usr/share/games folder for games? To me it seems the /usr/share/ directory is a shared directory for all users on the linux machine.